# How to explore git@heroku repository?

Tags: git, heroku, github

I have an app hosted @ heroku server. And they are showing my repository as 
**git@heroku.com:sharp-window-7156.git**. I have an account on github **https://github.com** also. Is it possible to explore and edit this respository from github?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do that with Github. If you use an IDE based Git tool like Gitx or Tower you should be able to browse the heroku repository otherwise you can just pull the code from the heroku origin and view it locally.

If you practice good source control/branch management though you can usually be sure that what's on github is on heroku. I usually always maintain my local master branch as the current 'live' code and work in branches. When I'm happy to put live the branch is merged into master, pushed to github and heroku.